# MIPS shift left/shift right

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, spim

I'm teaching myself MIPS and came across this piece of code:

```
or $t0 $z0 $t1
srl $t0 1 $t0
sll $t0 1 $t0
sub $t0 $t0 $t1
```

the part here that interests me is that `srl $t0 1 $t0` & `sll $t0 1 $t0` is this correct? As i thought it would be `srl $t0 $t0 1` with the n value last.

Also if $t1 contained 5, which is 00000101 when I do srl followed by sll would i just end up with something like this:
00000101

```
srl : 00000010
sll : 00000100
```

so $t0 would now be 4?

and then the sub part would be 5-4 which is 1?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes normally it has the form:

```
sll $t0 $t1 n
```

(or srl)

and yes you are right because logical shifts introduce 0's so your 5 would end up being a 4

and finally:

```
sub $t0 $t0 $t1
```

is equivalent to t0 = t0 - t1